# Debug Equinox SDK with source jars attached

Tags: java, eclipse, equinox, p2

I downloaded Equinox SDK Mars 1 for the purpose of debugging and observing the launch procedure of Eclipse. I am attempting to use the source jars that we obtain along with the distribution for Equinox framework and P2 for the debug procedure.

Currently, I have created a config.ini file as a configuration file and tried running the org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_(version).jar in command line but when I run it, there doesn't seem to be any response until I shutdown the SDK. Plus, my efforts of using the source jars and running the SDK for debugging has been futile.

I would be grateful if anyone can provide me any assistance with this case.

Comment: What do you want to debug exactly? The launcher is only a wrapper for the framework file org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.101.v20150820-1432.jar

If you are interested in Equinox framework only use a OSGi starter kit from here. http://download.eclipse.org/equinox/drops/R-Mars-201506032000/index.php.

Answer (score 0):

If you download the [Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/mars1).
Launch it go the Plug-ins View and search for "org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.101.v20150820-1432.jar" and select context-menu "Import As -> Source Project". Then open the class EclipseStarter.java and set your break point in main" -> Now your are ready for debugging equinox OSGi.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to debug the Equinox framework and P2 code by attached source jars method through IntelliJ. I am not entirely sure whether this is the best procedure but it served my purpose.

1. Since I wanted to observe the dropins capability of Equinox P2, I extracted the org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.source_(version).jar of Equinox SDK's plugins folder and opened it in IntelliJ. Then I added breakpoints to any positions I wanted.
2. Since this is just a foler, we are to setup our Java SDK. Simply select the Java SDK you require for the opened project.
3. You can then add new libraries through File-> Project Structure -> Libraries tag. You can add (+ sign) a library, a new Java project library and select the bundle you want to add from the Equinox SDK's plugins set.

You will be able to see under Classes heading in the sub window of Project Structure window, the new jar has been added. In the sub window, you can select + further to attach a source jar for the already selected jar.

For example, if you selected org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.manipulator_(version).jar from plugins, you can then select org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.manipulator.source_(version).jar as the corresponding source jar by using the above method.

You can select the library jar file and select the breakpoints in the corresponding source jar attached.

4. Run org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_(version).jar by setting up a debugging configuration. (ex: java -jar -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_(version).jar)

**Note**: It has to be stated that this method does have one known drawback already as we cannot save any changes (ex: added breakpoints) and each time we have to carry out the above setup. But yet this served my purpose of carrying out debugging for the Equinox code.